# Place files from project sub-folder into output directory

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, directory

I want to create a folder inside a C# project to contain some configuration files. However, I don't want these files to be copied to `bin\Release\MyFolder`. I'd rather have them copied to `bin\Release` directly. I'm thinking this may be doable by having a "virtual" folder, like solution folders, but I don't know how to do it.

Is there a way to create a virtual folder in Visual Studio 2008 (C#) projects? Or even better, how can I specify that the (text) file output should be directed to the main output folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file with a Post-build event.

Comment: Thanks. It's certainly a solution, but I was hoping I could find something simpler.

Comment: You can choose the output folder regardless of where your files are kept.

Right click on project and select properties. Click on Output tab.

Comment: @Sir Psycho: Yes, but I am asking about a particular set of files, not the whole project.

Answer (score -1):

In the Solution view (**View|Solution Explorer**), right-click on a project and select **Add -> New Filter**.  Type in a name for the filter (which looks like a folder in your project) and then you can add existing files to the filter by right-clicking and selecting **Add -> Existing Item**.

Comment: Is this VS 2008? I don't seem to have these options.

Comment: Me too, I can't find the filter option.

Comment: This is in VS2008 Pro.  It works in VS2005 as well.  No idea why this would be missing!

Comment: I have 2008 Pro as well, but I still don't find it!

Comment: New Filter is as far as I know only available for Visual C++, not the .NET environments. I guess it will be lost for C++ as well in 2010 because the project format will be the same as for the .NET languages.