# Add Solution Folder for VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I just started to use VS 2008 Express. I noticed that I cannot add a new solution folder within a solution in the way like VS 2005 Prof. Not sure if this feature is disabled in the Express version or not.

In VS 2005, I can also add project within a virtual solution folder. This makes my projects in a well organized tree. However, I cannot add virtual folder within a solution in VS 2008 (express?). I am not sure if I could add projects within a virtual folder (if possible in Prof) or not.

I even tried to use text editor to add folder structure in sln file like VS 2005 sln file. However VS 2008 complains the virtual folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a question in your post, but yes, the express edition disables this functionality. Consider it another reason to shell out the money for a higher tier.

Comment: so the virtual folder feature does exist in VS 2008 Prof, right?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. As discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479074/how-do-i-create-a-virtual-folder-in-a-visual-studio-2008-project C++ projects have "Add > New Filter" but C# projects only have "Add > New Folder".